# To Calculate Ageing Buckets, Based on Number of Days

Tags: unix, awk

Would like to generate report, which calculate the number of days, the material is in the warehouse. 
The number of days is the difference between date `($3 field)` the material comes in and 
the day  when the report is generated `(05-NOV-2014)` to view the inventory. 
Now, how do i go about with this. And, once i get the number of days, 
These must be categorised as

```
CAT-1 for the days 0-30Days,CAT-2 for days 31-60Days,CAT-3 for days 61-90Days,CAT-4 for days 91-180Days,
CAT-5 for days 181-365Days,CAT-6 for days 365-730Days,CAT-7 for days Greaterthan>730Days
```

against `Product($4) and Material($5)` wise combinations.

Input.csv

```
Des11,Des22,DateIn,Product,Material,Loc11,Loc22

10,a,15-SEP-14.11:09:06,ab,pq,yyy,zzz
20,a,23-SEP-14.08:09:35,ab,pq,yyy,zzz
10,a,15-MAY-14.08:09:26,ab,pq,yyy,zzz
62,a,17-FEB-12.03:09:23,ab,pq,yyy,zzz
10,a,04-NOV-14.11:09:06,cd,rs,yyy,zzz
20,a,12-AUG-14.08:09:35,cd,rs,yyy,zzz
10,a,16-DEC-13.08:09:26,cd,rs,yyy,zzz
62,a,18-DEC-13.03:09:23,cd,rs,yyy,zzz
```

For example , i am calulating the Aging bucket like below manually :
Date of Report generation is manual feed , so i can able to use any format like 05-Nov-14 or 05-NOV-2014 or 20141105 
however , i don't have any rights to change that input feed i.e 15-SEP-14.11:09:06

```
DateofReportGen,DateIn($3),DateIn,NoOfDays,Ageing Bucket
05-Nov-14,15-SEP-14.11:09:06,15-Sep-14,51,31-60Days
05-Nov-14,23-SEP-14.08:09:35,23-Sep-14,43,31-60Days
05-Nov-14,15-MAY-14.08:09:26,15-May-14,174,91-180Days
05-Nov-14,17-FEB-12.03:09:23,17-Feb-12,992,Greaterthan>730Days
05-Nov-14,04-NOV-14.11:09:06,04-Nov-14,1,0-30Days
05-Nov-14,12-AUG-14.08:09:35,12-Aug-14,85,61-90Days
05-Nov-14,16-DEC-13.08:09:26,16-Dec-13,324,181-365Days
05-Nov-14,18-DEC-13.03:09:23,18-Dec-13,322,181-365Days
```

I am trying to find "No of Days" but got struck

```
awk -F, -v q='"' '{
 c="date -d"q$3q" +%s";c|getline d1;close(c); 
 c="date -d"q05-NOV-14q" +%s";c|getline d2;close(c);
 printf "%s,%d\n", $0,(d2-d1)/3600/24}' Input.csv
```

Desired Output:

Count of Product and Material wise based on Ageing Bucket:

```
Product,Material,0-30Days,31-60Days,61-90Days,91-180Days,181-365Days,365-730Days,Greaterthan>730Days
ab,pq,0,2,0,1,0,0,1
cd,rs,1,0,1,0,2,0,0
```

I am looking for your suggestions , don't have Perl/Python access !!!

**Edit#1:** Thanks gboffi for your inputs, while executing this below script, i am getting "elapsed_days" as `16410.3` for all the line items ... Please suggest

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 {print}
         NR>1  {date=$3;
                gsub("[-.]"," ",date);
                printf $0 ",";system("date --date=\"" date "\" +%s")}
'  $filename | awk -F, -v OFS=, -v now=`date +%s` '
         NR==1 {print $0 ",elapsed_days"}
         NR>1  {$8=now-$8; $8=$8/24/3600;print $0}' Input.csv
```

**Output - Edit#1:**

```
Des11,Des22,DateIn,Product,Material,Loc11,Loc22,elapsed_days
10,a,15-SEP-14.11:09:06,ab,pq,yyy,zzz,16410.3
20,a,23-SEP-14.08:09:35,ab,pq,yyy,zzz,16410.3
10,a,15-MAY-14.08:09:26,ab,pq,yyy,zzz,16410.3
62,a,17-FEB-12.03:09:23,ab,pq,yyy,zzz,16410.3
10,a,04-NOV-14.11:09:06,cd,rs,yyy,zzz,16410.3
20,a,12-AUG-14.08:09:35,cd,rs,yyy,zzz,16410.3
10,a,16-DEC-13.08:09:26,cd,rs,yyy,zzz,16410.3
62,a,18-DEC-13.03:09:23,cd,rs,yyy,zzz,16410.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a two passes solution

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 {print}
         NR>1  {date=$3;
                gsub("[-.]"," ",date);
                printf $0 ",";system("date --date=\"" date "\" +%s")}
'  $filename | awk -F, -v OFS=, -v now=`date +%s` '
         NR==1 {print $0 ",elapsed_days"}
         NR>1  {$8=now-$8; $8=$8/24/3600;print $0}'
```

of course when you have the number of days in `$8` you can format your final output as you please.

***In response to OP problems***

What follows is copied and pasted from my terminal,

1. I show you my version of your data, copied and pasted from your original post,

   ```
   % cat dates
   Des11,Des22,DateIn,Product,Material,Loc11,Loc22
   10,a,15-SEP-14.11:09:06,ab,pq,yyy,zzz
   20,a,23-SEP-14.08:09:35,ab,pq,yyy,zzz
   10,a,15-MAY-14.08:09:26,ab,pq,yyy,zzz
   62,a,17-FEB-12.03:09:23,ab,pq,yyy,zzz
   10,a,04-NOV-14.11:09:06,cd,rs,yyy,zzz
   20,a,12-AUG-14.08:09:35,cd,rs,yyy,zzz
   10,a,16-DEC-13.08:09:26,cd,rs,yyy,zzz
   62,a,18-DEC-13.03:09:23,cd,rs,yyy,zzz
   ```
2. I execute ONLY the first part of the 2 stages pipeline

   ```
   % awk -F, 'NR==1 {print}
              NR>1  {date=$3;
                     gsub("[-.]"," ",date);
                     printf $0 ",";system("date --date=\"" date "\" +%s")}
   ' dates 
   Des11,Des22,DateIn,Product,Material,Loc11,Loc22
   10,a,15-SEP-14.11:09:06,ab,pq,yyy,zzz,1410772146
   20,a,23-SEP-14.08:09:35,ab,pq,yyy,zzz,1411452575
   10,a,15-MAY-14.08:09:26,ab,pq,yyy,zzz,1400134166
   62,a,17-FEB-12.03:09:23,ab,pq,yyy,zzz,1329444563
   10,a,04-NOV-14.11:09:06,cd,rs,yyy,zzz,1415095746
   20,a,12-AUG-14.08:09:35,cd,rs,yyy,zzz,1407823775
   10,a,16-DEC-13.08:09:26,cd,rs,yyy,zzz,1387177766
   62,a,18-DEC-13.03:09:23,cd,rs,yyy,zzz,1387332563
   ```

   please note in the output above the last field, that contains the output of the system's `date` command
3. I finally execute the whole pipeline, and the number of elapsed days is different in each line.
   What's gone wrong with your procedure? look at the output of the date command for, e.g., `date --date="15 SEP 14 11:09:06" +%s`, if that it's not the problem, what else?

   ```
   % awk -F, 'NR==1 {print}
              NR>1  {date=$3;
                     gsub("[-.]"," ",date);
                     printf $0 ",";system("date --date=\"" date "\" +%s")}
   ' dates | awk -F, -v OFS=, -v now=`date +%s` '
             NR==1 {print $0 ",elapsed_days"}
             NR>1  {$8=now-$8; $8=$8/24/3600;print $0}'
   Des11,Des22,DateIn,Product,Material,Loc11,Loc22,elapsed_days
   10,a,15-SEP-14.11:09:06,ab,pq,yyy,zzz,81.9347
   20,a,23-SEP-14.08:09:35,ab,pq,yyy,zzz,74.0593
   10,a,15-MAY-14.08:09:26,ab,pq,yyy,zzz,205.059
   62,a,17-FEB-12.03:09:23,ab,pq,yyy,zzz,1023.23
   10,a,04-NOV-14.11:09:06,cd,rs,yyy,zzz,31.893
   20,a,12-AUG-14.08:09:35,cd,rs,yyy,zzz,116.059
   10,a,16-DEC-13.08:09:26,cd,rs,yyy,zzz,355.018
   62,a,18-DEC-13.03:09:23,cd,rs,yyy,zzz,353.226
   %
   ```

Comment: Thanks gboffi for your inputs, while executing the above script for all the line items , am getting "elapsed_days" as -16410.3

Comment: Des11,Des22,DateIn,Product,Material,Loc11,Loc22,elapsed_days
10,a,15-SEP-14.11:09:06,ab,pq,yyy,zzz,16410.3
20,a,23-SEP-14.08:09:35,ab,pq,yyy,zzz,16410.3
10,a,15-MAY-14.08:09:26,ab,pq,yyy,zzz,16410.3
62,a,17-FEB-12.03:09:23,ab,pq,yyy,zzz,16410.3
10,a,04-NOV-14.11:09:06,cd,rs,yyy,zzz,16410.3
20,a,12-AUG-14.08:09:35,cd,rs,yyy,zzz,16410.3
10,a,16-DEC-13.08:09:26,cd,rs,yyy,zzz,16410.3
62,a,18-DEC-13.03:09:23,cd,rs,yyy,zzz,16410.3

Comment: Thanks a lot gboffi , It's working fine , I have accepted the answer and upvoted !!!

Comment: gboffi , I would like to find "elapsed_day" from 01-DEC-2014 instead of sytem date, please suggest where to change the command !!!

Comment: The reference date is set, in the second `awk` command, by the fragment `-v now=`date +%s` that gives you the so called `epoch` at the moment of the invocation of the script.  If you want to use a different date change `date +%s` to `date --date="01 DEC 2014 " +%s` (note the spaces intead of your hyphens: side note, the `date` command is really flexible with respect to its input, but doesn't like your specific input... if you can change the date format I'd recommend the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format specification).